# Git ignore not ignoring file

Tags: git

I have a .gitignore file set up with the following:

```
.DS_Store
secret_key.py
```

And here is my file structure

```
├── README.md
├── app
│   ├── secret_key.py
├── .gitignore
```

Totally new to using .gitignore so please forgive my ignorance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make Git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/how-to-make-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: Is the file already being tracked by git? If you make a change to the file does git see that change?